# User permissions for upload in azure web app

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I have an azure web app (mvc core 2).  It uses an occasionally updated data file.  It is stored in a folder off wwwroot.  I wish to allow users in a specific role to be able to upload a new copy of the data file maybe once per day or two days.  The datafile is less than 1MB.The datafile should not be generally viewable

Can I set permissions on the folder to let me do this and if so how?

Martin

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is can be done with [Azure blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction).  Blob storage is designed for serving images or documents directly to a browser, storing files for distributed access, streaming video and audio and much more. Users or client applications can access objects in Blob storage via HTTP/HTTPS.

As for the permissions on the folder, I believe the SAS token could implement it. With a SAS, you can grant clients access to resources in your storage account, without sharing your account keys. This is the key point of using shared access signatures in your applications--a SAS is a secure way to share your storage resources without compromising your account keys. About the deteails you could refer to this doc: [Using shared access signatures (SAS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1).

Comment: I was rather hoping I didn't have to use azure blob storage Sit is just a single file less than 1MB in size.  Maybe I should store it in sql server instead.

Comment: I did t have a permission problem. Hadnt done my path combi e properly.   Doh!

Comment: @Martin, what you are using now? Blob or sql.

Comment: I am actually using the file system. It just works.    I allways felt it should.  Especially as I had another bit of cose which read that file and rewrote customised version of it in a subfolder.  I can see no reason why using sql server wouldn't have worked tho.